# url rewriting and moving of questionmark

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've tried all manor of rules and just can work this one out. If there someone who can solve this?

I need to turn this

```
http://localhost/search/?terms=foobar
```

into this

```
http://localhost/index.php?m=search&terms=foobar
```

Where "foobar" is really ([^/]*), ie can be anything, it's a search string.
The initial URL has a "?" in it due to the GET method of HTML forms. Although it would be easier without that "?" it's not something that can be done?

I've tried the following with no luck.

```
#RewriteRule ^search/\?terms\=([^/]*)$ index.php?m=search&terms=$1 [L]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For query string you need to use `%{QUERY_STRING}`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^terms=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^search/?$ index.php?m=search&terms=%1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match QUERY_STRING in RewriteRule. Have your code like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(search)/?$ index.php?m=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Because of `QSA` flag `%{QUERY_STRING}` will automatically be carried over to new URL.